# how to extract element from numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

```
ls_ord_symbols     = np.zeros((len(na_csv_orders), 1), dtype='S5')

>>> print ls_ord_symbols
[['AAPL']
 ['IBM']
 ['GOOG']]

>>> print type(ls_ord_symbols)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> print type(ls_ord_symbols[0])
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> print ls_ord_symbols[0][0]
AAPL
>>> print type(ls_ord_symbols[0][0])
<type 'numpy.string_'>
>>> print str(ls_ord_symbols[0][0])
AAPL
>>> print type(str(ls_ord_symbols[0][0]))
<type 'str'>
```

Question> I need to extract each element stored inside numpy.array with the original type. Here, `ls_ord_symbols` stores the string inside a numpy.array.

I have to use the following way to extract the raw element:

```
str(ls_ord_symbols[i][0])
```

Is there a better way to do this given the index `i`? Basically, I expect to simply get the list of ['AAPL', 'IBM', 'GOOG'] or 'AAPL', 'IBM', 'GOOG' as each individual string while iterate through this numpy.array with index `i`

Comment: Look at `ls_ord_symbols.shape`.  You might see that you have an extra dimension that you don't need/want.

Comment: When you put a string into a numpy array the "original type" is lost, as numpy converts everything to its own optimized types.  If you want a regular string you will need to convert the numpy types yourself (as you are doing with `str`).  (Why do you need it to be a "real" str?)

Comment: I just need to get a list of string and use np.zeros to do that. Because I thought [].append(string) will be expensive and slow.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np
ls_ord_symbols = np.zeros((3, 1), dtype='S5')
ls_ord_symbols[0,0] = 'AAPL'
ls_ord_symbols[1,0] = 'IBM'
ls_ord_symbols[2,0] = 'GOOG'
mylist = [ls_ord_symbols[i,0]
          for i in xrange(ls_ord_symbols.shape[0])]
print repr(mylist)
```

Comment: It seems that I should instead use list.append.

Comment: This still is the same type, `numpy.string_`